# How to get Comma in Integer from string

Tags: c#, string, parsing, integer, concatenation

I have two integer values for example `25` and `3`.Now i want to add these into one single integer but the condition is that both these values should be separated by Comma (,).If its Possible How can it be done.It is giving me error as comma can not be conactenated in integer..
I have tried like this ..

```
 int inoutSpecifierPosition = (startIndex + "," + difference);
```

but it is giving me error ..Please help me ...

Any Suggestion will be highly appreciated ...

Comment: You should look up topics like "numeric string conversion" and "string concatenation".

Comment: Comma in integer? What? Are you sure you understand what is an Integer?

Answer (score 5):

It is impossible to have an integer like `25,3`. It can be a `string` instead like;

```
string inoutSpecifierPosition = startIndex + "," + difference;
```

No integer can have any comma or any decimal separator or thousand separator character. They are *just* numbers. Only their string representations can have. That's why your

> *Now i want to add these into one single integer but the condition is that both these values should be separated by comma*

statement is meaningless.

Your code gives error because `string + int` returns `string`, not `int`.

There are 3 [`+`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1a63xkz.aspx) operator overload in string concatenation in .NET Framework.

From C# Spec [$7.8.4 Addition operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691375%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
string operator + (string x, string y);
string operator + (string x, object y);
string operator + (object x, string y);
```

> These overloads of the binary + operator perform string concatenation.
>   If an operand of string concatenation is null, an empty string is
>   substituted. **Otherwise, any non-string argument is converted to its
>   string representation by invoking the virtual ToString method
>   inherited from type object**.

If you want to format your integers as a string, you can use [`string.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) like;

```
string s = string.Format("{0},{1}", startIndex, difference); // 25,3
```

If you *already* have `25,3` as a string you want to get these integers, you can use [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Int32.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods like;

```
string s = "25,3";
int startIndex = Int32.Parse(s.Split(',')[0]);
int difference = Int32.Parse(s.Split(',')[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

No you can't . ',' is a string . you can't put these combinly in a int but you can put this in string

```
string inoutSpecifierPosition = (startIndex + "," + difference);
```

later you can split it into int again

```
var integers=inoutSpecifierPosition.Split(',');
int a=int.Parse(integers[0]);
int b = int.Parse(integers[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add a comma it will not be an integer anymore, it will be become a string, or a double/decimal depending on your culture.

Lets assume it's a string.  You will want

```
var newValue = string.format("{0},{1}", startIndex, difference);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, integers don't have fractions. It's a whole number, so you can't set anything behind the comma.

Second, you need something like a `decimal`:

```
decimal inoutSpecifierPosition = startIndex + difference / 100; // divide by 100 for example if `difference` can't exceed 100.
```

Or `string` to get the data in:

```
string inoutSpecifierPosition = string.Format("{0},{1}", startIndex, difference);
```